# Solr 6.2.1 combine sort

Tags: sorting, solr

I hava a question with solr sort. I load some data into singleinstance solr with two field :

```
field name="timestamp" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"

field name="sequence" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"
```

then I query it with the

```
url：http://localhost:8080/solr/second/select?q=*%3A*%0A&sort=timestamp+asc%2Csequence+asc+&fl=timestamp%2Csequence&wt=json&indent=true
```

but the result is that

```
"sort":"timestamp asc,sequence asc ",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":3000,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "timestamp":1000001210375,
        "sequence":5},
      {
        "timestamp":1000001995899,
        "sequence":9},
      {
        "timestamp":1000002980757,
        "sequence":7},
      {
        "timestamp":1000005311535,
        "sequence":5},
      {
        "timestamp":1000007582420,
        "sequence":0},
      {
        "timestamp":1000007754398,
        "sequence":0},
      {
        "timestamp":1000007820065,
        "sequence":5},
      {
        "timestamp":1000008875407,
        "sequence":7},
      {
        "timestamp":1000009462491,
        "sequence":5},
      {
        "timestamp":1000010136221,
        "sequence":1}]
  }}
```

It sort timestamp in right way, but not sort sequence in asc

Anyone know why?thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It sorts by timestamp first then sequence, so it will only sort by the sequence value when timestamp values are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've got it!